# Django Models - SELECT DISTINCT(foo) FROM table is too slow

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a MySQL table with 13M rows. I can query the db directly as

```
SELECT DISTINCT(refdate) FROM myTable
```

The query takes 0.15 seconds and is great.

The equivalent table defined as a Django model and queried as

```
myTable.objects.values(`refdate`).distinct()
```

takes a very long time. Is it because there are too many items in the list before `distinct()`. How do I do this in a manner that doesn't bring everything down?

Comment: The SQL generated by your code above will be pretty much the same as what you run manually: `SELECT DISTINCT mytable.refdate FROM mytable` so it's weird that it runs so much slower. can you profile using django-debug-toolbar to make sure that it is the query itself that is so slow?

Comment: I have tried using the django model from python shell and had the issue outlined above. I never even got to trying to load a page and watching it hang.

Comment: Can you dump `connection.queries` after running the query in shell? (`from django.db import connection`)?

Comment: @solarissmoke **Thank you!** That helped me fill in the blanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @solarissmoke for the pointer to `connection.queries`.

I was expecting to see

```
SELECT DISTINCT refdate FROM myTable
```

Instead, I got

```
SELECT DISTINCT refdate, itemIndex, itemType FROM myTable ORDER BY itemIndex, refdate, itemType.
```

I then looked at myTable defined in `models.py`.

```
unique_together = (('nodeIndex', 'refdate', 'nodeType'), )
ordering = ['nodeIndex', 'refdate', 'nodeType']
```

From [Interaction with default ordering or order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

> normally you won’t want extra columns playing a part in the result, so clear out the ordering, or at least make sure it’s restricted only to those fields you also select in a values() call.

So I tried `order_by()` to flush the previously defined ordering and voila!

```
myTable.objects.values('refdate').order_by().distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myTable.objects.all().distinct('refdate')
```

Comment: `distinct()` with positional arguments is only supported on PostgreSQL.